# Import specific cmdlets from modules to use in Runspacepool

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

In C#, InitialSessionState class provides a way to import specific modules and make it available to all the runspaces in the runspacepool using "ImportPSModule" method. (But this imports all cmdlets in the module being imported)

To import specific cmdlets from a module, "Import-Module" command accepts a parameter "Cmdlet", using which we can import only specific cmdltes from that module. **How to achieve this behaviour (importing only specific cmdlets from module) in Runspacepool**

Comment: Why is this needed? If it is needed for performance/resource reasons then I would not bother, I do not think there is a significant difference, if any.

Answer (score 2):

You can add commands to the `Commands` Property of your InitialSessionState instance (here using a `Cmdlet` type command as an example):

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
SessionStateCmdletEntry resolveCmdlet = new SessionStateCmdletEntry("Resolve-DnsName", 
    typeof(Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName), 
    "dnslookup.dll-Help.xml");
iss.Commands.Add(resolveCmdlet);
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
```